# Check a Excel Cell in a thread

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt

In python how can it be checked for a cell value in an excel file if it is non zero and some processing can be done? The condition is that the check would be in a thread which will keep checking if a particular value has some value. And when the program is running i.e the thread checking, a user enters some value in that cell, so the program should be able to read that value.

When I tried to do this I am facing an IO error.

Can any body help me?

Comment: What does the error states?

Comment: Permission denied, as may be the file is opened while the program tries to use it

Comment: Try opening in read only mode

Answer (score 0):

When excel programs take hold of files, they lock them, and another program (your thread) won't be able to access the file.

You probably looking at a polling the file between sleeps. So Why don't you just handle that exception in your thread:

```
while checking_cell:
    sleep(delay):
    try:
        # open the document
    except:  ## Use your error here is best practice, you wont want to catch them all!
        # handle the exception
    else:
        # check the cell value
```